# Spring task scheduler runs a single task multiple times

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, spring-mvc, scheduled-tasks

I have a scheduler that runs every minute using Spring's task namespace. As per the documentation it should run once using one of the threads in the cached pool with a delay of 1 minute. But it runs another time after a random amount of time, say 5 seconds on a different thread than the one it ran previously. Not to mention, after 1 minute it will run the one which is supposed to run. But the 5 seconds one is not supposed to run. I've seen similar questions in SO but there was no reported solution. In my case it works fine in my local environment and this issue only happens on Development Environment. Is there anything wrong with this Spring feature?

```
<task:annotation-driven scheduler="myScheduler" />
<task:scheduler id="myScheduler" pool-size="10"/>
<task:scheduled-tasks scheduler="myScheduler">
    <task:scheduled ref="mySchedulerBean"
                    method="doSomething" fixed-delay="60000" />
</task:scheduled-tasks>

<bean id="mySchedulerBean" class="com.mycompany.app.tasks.SchedulerBean"/>
```

Comment: Any chance this context snippet is deployed two times?

Comment: @DirkLachowski No, the only difference between local and development is the server instance and a few settings. I'm not sure how it would affect.

Comment: Could you elaborate on the "few settings"? The feature is definitivly not broken in spring (btw.: What version are you using?).

Comment: After doing some research, found that it was broken in previous versions of spring, fortunately I'm using the fix version which is 3.2.2. But you were right, the context is deployed twice, will detail the change in answer.

Comment: By version i meant spring's version. 3.2.2 is rather old.

Comment: Sorry I mistook you, but they say it's fixed in 3.2.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are using older versions of spring, they need to upgrade to atleast 3.2.2.
And if it still doesn't fix the problem, then the context is most likely deployed twice. Check the app server deployment configuration to solve the problem or in some other cases, you might be doing annotation based scheduling and also be using task xml namespace, you can use either one but not both.